# MySql return only one instance of duplicate entries

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have a table with names and numbers entered along with other data . The table called events contains many instances where the name and numbers are the same but the other entries are different. I want to perform a search using names so I can display the number. But in my search I only need to return one instance of a name . The table is like this

```
        Name    Number  Responisble     Position

        Paul    8455    Chorley     t7
        Dave    3821    PR south    f5
        Paul    8455    PR North    p9
        Paul    8455    Leyland     t6
        Dave    3821    Ribbleton   r4
```

and my script is this

```
    $condition = "name LIKE 'Paul' ";
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE $condition ")  ;

     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
```

The script is not complete but I hope you can see that the results would return 3 results but what i want is a result with just one for each name

I hope this makes sense ! thanks for any help

Answer (score 3):

```
$condition = "name LIKE 'Paul' ";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE $condition GROUP BY name")  ;
```

Answer (score 1):

try using [distinct](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html) -

`SELECT DISTINCT (columns) FROM (table) WHERE (condition)`

**edit** probably disregard this, mis-understood your question i think

> MySql return only one instance of duplicate entries

Answer (score 0):

You can either use group by or distinct in the select statement see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html

In your example it would be

```
$condition = "name LIKE 'Paul' ";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE $condition GROUP BY name")  ;

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, number FROM events WHERE $condition GROUP BY name, number
```